# What is the time cost of creating a String in Java, with respect to JVM's string pool?

Tags: java, string, jvm

Java has a string pool and therefore before a new string is actually created I guess there is a check to see if the same string already exists, what is the cost of this call?

Is the pool a hash or tree based structure?

In either case I guess comes down to the performance of the String hash code, as search trees use hash code as a key?

I'm guessing its about log n, where n is the number of strings currently on the heap.

Comment: As I understand it only strings that are known at compile time are pooled. There is no runtime check

Comment: @RichardTingle no object pool exists at compile time. Everything comes into existence during execution.

Comment: Are yes that would make sense.

Comment: @JunedAhsan **Known** at compile time

Comment: The pool / chache is only for literals, i.e. constant String known at compile time. If you create a String using the new operator then it will be a new instance regardless whether it has already been declared as literal or not.

Comment: Maybe the compiler just creates a static string and replaces repeated strings with that static reference?

Comment: @A4L, sure but how does it pool / cache the literals, is it a dynamic systems at runtime, or does the compiler replace literals with a reference to a static?

Comment: @user1037729: You have it backwards:  The compiler replaces all static  final references Strings with the String literal.

Comment: @MadConan that doesn't make sense to me, why would it create more instances when it doesn't need to, surely the compiler would scan through the java code and if it finds a repeated string literal it would create a static and reference this.. are this would mean the string would never get GC'd this means a string dynamic pool must be  used, if so how is this pool implemented, tree, hash table...?

Comment: @user1037729:  See the edit to my answer.  That doesn't create more instances.  It simply points the reference to the same instance.  It sounds like you need to do some research on the terminology of reference and instance in Java, as well as basic memory allocation.

Answer (score 7):

From [this unofficial blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20151209084324/http://www.precisejava.com/javaperf/j2se/StringAndStringBuffer.htm)

> Java Virtual Machine maintains an internal list of references for interned Strings ( pool of unique Strings) to avoid duplicate String objects in heap memory. Whenever the JVM loads String literal from class file and executes, it checks whether that String exists in the internal list or not. If it already exists in the list, then it  does not create a new String and it uses reference to the existing String Object.
>
> **JVM does this type of checking internally for String literal but not for String object which it creates through 'new' keyword**. You can explicitly force JVM to do this type of checking for String objects which are created through '`new`' keyword using `String.intern()` method. This forces JVM to check the internal list and use the existing String object if it is already present.

Comment: how is this pool implemented, I'd like to know this do I can work out the pool look up time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no check whether a new string is already in the string pool, this is one of the reasons why you should not use `==` to compare strings.

The string pool is used for strings that are known at compile time. Or if you manually use `intern()` and use the returned instance.

Comment: how does it pool / cache the literals, does the compiler replace literals with a reference to a static?

Answer (score 0):

Every time a String is created dynamically at runtime, a new String instance is returned. The String pool only contains String literals and String compile-time constants, or Strings that have explicitely been added to the pool by calling [`String.intern()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29).

Comment: I'm asking how is the pooling mechanism implemented so I can understand the look up time

Comment: @user1037729 Are you calling the intern() method on your strings? if so profile

Comment: I'm not calling intern()

Comment: @user1037729 Then there is no pooling of strings other than compile time known strings, like "hello world". All this stuff happens before your program (properly) starts

Comment: sure, so how does java achieve this, is it by replacing the literals with static references?

Answer (score 0):

Any String that can, at compile time, be known is pooled, this means the following creates only one string. (String literals are the most obvious of example, but any compile time constant string is pooled)

```
static final String a= "hello world";
static final String b= "hello world";
static final String c= "hello" + " world";
```

However, any string which is created during the normal run of the program is not pooled and so no such check exists unless you explicitely call `.intern()`

Answer (score 0):

When a JVM is running, only constant Strings (i.e. hard coded)  are in the String pool.

```
public class StringExample{
    private static final String CONSTANT = "Cannon Ball!!!"; // <- In the pool
    public void processStrings(String[] args){
                               //        ^--Assumed contents are variables, not in the pool
        String temp = "I'll wade in."; // <- In the pool
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100);
        sb.append("I").append(" hate").append(" water.");  
        String dynamic = sb.toString(); //  <- Not in the pool.
        dynamic.intern(); // <- Now it's in the pool.

    }
}
```

All dynamic strings are external to the String pool.  You can programatically add Strings to the pool by calling `String.intern()`.

---

EDIT:  To address your comment to your question:  When you have something like the following:

```
public class StringExample{
   public static final String CONSTANT = "Just me.";
}
public class Foo{
   private String value = StringExample.CONSTANT;
}
```

At compile time, the compiler simply replaces the reference with the hard-coded string, so it would be the equivalent of doing

```
public class StringExample{
   public static final String CONSTANT = "Just me.";
}
public class Foo{
   private String value = "Just me.";
}
```

Comment: Your answer is self-contradictory.

Comment: @EJP Your comment is meaningless without an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

> Java has a string pool and therefore before a new string is actually created I guess there is a check to see if the same string already exists, what is the cost of this call?

This only happens for String literals, not Strings you create.  You can call String.intern() to add it to the pool, but only after it has been created.

> Is the pool a hash or tree based structure?

Its a fixed size hash map with linked list for collisions.  I suggest you not over use this. As it doesn't scale.

> In either case I guess comes down to the performance of the String hash code, as search trees use hash code as a key?

If you need a String pool I suggest you write one yourself.  I have one which takes a `byte[]` or a `CharSequence` such a StringBuilder and pools the String so it doesn't create objects around 90% of the time (that is the target)

> I'm guessing its about log n, where n is the number of strings currently on the heap.

Actually is O(1) up to around 10,000 which is the capacity, after that it is O(n) which is not great.

> how does it pool / cache the literals, does the compiler replace literals with a reference to a static? –

The compiler combines String literals in a given class file, but the JVM takes that and combines them for the whole JVM.